# Where in the Tale of Genji does it say Genji's affair offends Amaterasu?

Tags: japanese-language, murasaki-shikibu, the-tale-of-genji

From Doris Bargen, *The Search for Things Past in the Genji monogatari*:

> The beginning of the Genji, as established by literary tradition, is
> indeed deceptively matter-of-fact about events of grave impact. Genji and his
> stepmother Fujitsubo commit symbolic incest. Since it is said that the
> Emperor Hsüan Tsung had originally intended Yang Kuei-fei for one of his
> sons, Genji’s incestuous love is an even closer analogy to the Chinese legend
> than his parents’ excessive but otherwise legitimate passion. With this form
> of illicit love, Genji does more than break a moral taboo; he violates a social
> religious taboo. To the pursuit of a mother figure is added the cuckolding of
> the father on the one hand and the blasphemous offense against the sun
> goddess Amaterasu-omikami on the other.

Bargen is very vague whether this is her own understanding or something that can be inferred from the original text. I don't see this offense mentioned in Genji. Amaterasu, the Japanese sun goddess, is mentioned a couple of times in The Tale of Genji, but not where Bargen is pointing us to -- Genji's affair with Fujitsubo, and not in the manner Bargen describes here. So where in the Tale of Genji does it tell us that Genji's affair with Fujitsubo offends Amaterasu?